# Wrong controller action invoked?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

```
Rails 3.2
```

This is my second attempt at solving this problem.

I inherited an application for processing customer tickets. The main ticket view, is large and complicated, so it's split up into multiple sections.

I am trying to add a new section to enter customers information.

I have a scaffolding for CustomerInfo, with a controller and a model, in the normal locations:

controllers/customer_infos_controller.rb and models/customer_info.rb.

I put the views under views/tickets/sections

In my views/tickets/show.html.slim, I have:

```
- @customer_info = customer_info @ticket
h4.form-header Customer Information
.form-section.attachments
  - if @customer_info.nil?
    = render partial: 'tickets/sections/customer_info', locals: {ticket:  @ticket }
```

In my , views/tickets/sections/_customer_info.html.slim, I have:

```
= form_for(CustomerInfo.new, url: customer_info_path) do |f|
  - f.hidden_field :ticket_id, :value => ticket.id
  .form-horizontal-column.customer-info
    .form-group
      = f.label :first
      = f.text_field :first, maxlength: 50
    .form-group
      = f.label :last
      = f.text_field :last, maxlength: 50
    .actions = f.submit 'Save'
.clear
```

In my routes.rb, I have:

```
post '/customer_infos' => 'customer_infos#create', as: 'customer_info'
```

When I run the application, the form displays properly. But, when I enter the first name, and last name, the ticket gets updated.

Looking at the log file, I see that when the Save button in the Customer Information section, I see:

Processing by TicketsController#update as HTML

In the log, I also saw the params:

```
{
    "ticket":
        {
            .......................
        },
    "customer_info":
        {
            "first":"John",
            "last":"Doe"
        },
    "commit":"Save"
}
```

rake routes gives me:

```
customer_info POST /customer_infos(.:format)  customer_infos#create
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="form-horizontal-column customer-info">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="customer_info_first">First *</label>
        <input id="customer_info_first" type="text" size="50" name="customer_info[first]" maxlength="50">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="customer_info_last">Post tax total *</label>
        <input id="customer_info_last" type="text" size="50" name="customer_info[last]" maxlength="50">
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" name="commit">
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the  portion:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="http://xxx.xxxx.xxxx.com/admin/tickets/159384" class="form form-horizontal tickets-form context-form" data-admin="true" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="edit_ticket_159384" method="post">
```

So, there is no customer_info  portion, with the proper action and method.

Why is the tickets controller update method is invoked, instead of the CustomerInfo create method? I also don't see the ticket_id param in the params.

Comment: What is output of 'rake routes' command, plus what is the actual HTML output for your form? Roughly, you add just a POST route, and form_for will use PATCH/PUT method that is redirected to update controller method. Check [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#translated-paths)

Comment: How do I get the actual HTML output for the form?

Comment: I added the output of the rake routes command to my question

Comment: View HTML output - view source in browser or use curl. Find the needed portion inside

Comment: I added the HTML to the question

Comment: paste the form HTML complete to see the action attribute and method

Comment: That's a lot of code, and it shows customers/companies confidential information. What exactly are you looking for, so I can see if I can find it (keywords, etc)

Comment: What is needed is <form> element, plus <input> with name '_method'. Actually, this was requested in above comment.

Comment: I already posted the inputs, I just added the <form> line.